# How to hide the URL extensions in a Spring Starter Project (STS in Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, .htaccess, spring-tool-suite

I work on a Spring Starter Project (Spring tools Suite) in Eclipse so I didn't have web.xml file to make URL-mappings.

I have a Controller, how can I do URL-mappings with `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping` to make my `/test.html` file accessible on `/test` url ?

Or do you have an other solution like a .htaccess file who work on this type of project ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: put your html files in `src/main/resources/templates/`, then write a controller method that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    @RequestMapping("/{template}")
    public String renderTemplate(@PathVariable String template) {
        return template;
    }
}
```

Spring Boot will know to look in `src/main/resources/templates` for a file called `${template}.html`, and will render it.